# SQL - Unique Foreign Key on per Foreigner Basis

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is this possible to achieve? A table of Interests for example, correspond to a table of users, with foreign key user_id corresponding to user(id), can I enforce uniqueness for column interests.name on a user_id basis?

Answer (score 0):

So you basically don't want multiple rows with the same interest for a single user_id, correct?

You need to create a unique constraint (index) on the combination of user_id and interest_id.

```
alter table interests add unique index(user_id, interest_id);
```

Comment: so would that be user_id, interest_id and not user_id AND interest_id?

Comment: oh and it would be user_id and name, maybe I was unclear, thanks I'll try this :)

Comment: Yep, an AND would not be an appropriate sub-clause for index definition.  In this case, it will ensure that the combination of user_id and interest_id is always unique, or else will throw a constraint violation.

Comment: name is the name of the interest, right?  Same deal though, just substitute name for interest_id.

Comment: You may actually want to create a table of interests, where each possible interest has an interest_id, along with a separate mapping table user_interests that stores the mappings from users to interests.  It would have two columns only, user_id, interest_id, where the interest table would have interest_id, name.

Comment: yeah I just thought of that instead... otherwise using a set of numbers in the users interests field

Comment: I would not recommend the set of numbers.  It gets very tricky, and very inefficient to query (because it can't really be indexed).

Comment: Using a separate linking table would make it impossible to have unique names on per user basis. The approach described in this answer is the way to go, I think (with `intersted_id` replaced by `name`, of course).

Comment: @andriy-m I would assume that there is a unique constraint on the interests table on the name, such that you cannot have two interests in the interests table with the same name.  Then, by extension, we are ensuring the combination of interest_id and user_id are unique in the mapping table.  I generally try to avoid putting unique constraints on varchar fields (other than for very short, well defined values like language codes), because they are far less efficient to index and search frequently than are integers.

Comment: @squawknull: Maybe I've simply misunderstood your requirement. I thought you wanted to guarantee uniqueness within any given group of same `user_id` rows, and if two same names had different user ids, it would be all right. If my understanding was correct then I cannot see how you are solving the problem with what you've just described. If not, I'm sorry for confusing you.

Comment: @squawknull: Sorry again, of course I was too hasty in my conclusion and your approach does solve the problem. Only it does not seem to allow you to have same names with different user ids, in case that is of any importance.

Comment: @andry-m It's not really my requirement, but I think I was getting at what @Supernovah wanted.  :)  It's also just a matter of efficiency.  If this is going to be a small database, it may be premature optimization, but if the database is going to have millions of rows, it gets important.  One can probably assume that the user_interests table is going to be far more volatile than the interest table, so basically, by putting the unique constraint on name in the interest table, mysql will have to do fewer string comparisons versus making it a key in the user_interest table, but to the same effect

Comment: @andriy-m that should work too.  There would be only one row in the interest table with a given name, and that would be identified by an interest_id.  Then, in the user_interest table, we define a unique index on (user_id, interest_id) such that we can have multiple users with the same interest and multiple interests with the same user, but never multiple rows containing the same user_id and interest_id.

Comment: @squawknull: Oh, that was so silly of me! I'm sorry, I thought I was talking to the OP! :) After so little sleeping it's just too early a morning.

Comment: @squawknull: Hey, I can see the idea now, thanks! Actually a nice alternative, that one. Only all other properties of `interests`, if  any, would also be shared.